# Problemas con una consulta en mi SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, server

Quiero ejecutar esta consulta de las órdenes de pacientes en la segunda quincena de junio:

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.PTA, B.ORD, A.NOM,A.DIR,A.INS, C.DES,B.PED, A.FCG,B.FEC_ATE,A.FNA, A.HCL,D.OBS, SUM (F.GTS) "UB"
FROM dbo.CLIPAC A
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIORD B ON  A.ORI=B.OPA 
AND A.PAC = B.PAC 
INNER JOIN dbo.CLINST C ON A.INS = C.INS
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIHCL D ON A.HCL = D.HCL
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIIOR E ON B.PTA = E.PTA AND B.PAC=E.ORD
INNER JOIN dbo.CLINOM F ON E.PFA= F.COD
WHERE A.OBS LIKE 'DOM%'  
AND A.NOM NOT LIKE '%ANULADA' 
AND F.CLA = 'NT'  
AND B.FEC_ATE BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-16),GETDATE()),103) 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE()))),DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())),103) 
GROUP BY B.PTA, B.ORD, A.NOM,A.DIR,A.INS, C.DES,B.PED, A.FCG,B.FEC_ATE,A.FNA, A.HCL,D.OBS
ORDER BY 9,1,2
```

Y me salta el siguiente error:

> Mens. 242, Nivel 16, Estado 3, Línea 1 The conversion of a varchar
> data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Hola Ornella. Aparentemente el campo FEC_ATE no del tipo varchar y debería ser datetime para poder compararse.

Comment: Tal como menciona @GustavoCantero si `B.FEC_ATE` es de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`, la conversión que haces a `VARCHAR` es innecesaria y de hecho es lo que te causa el problema, quita los `CONVERT` y debería funcionar. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: agrego que la conversión no necesariamente es el proble, el problema es el formato  (103) ya que es ambigua para volver a ser fecha, ¿Por que conviertes a `VARCHAR(25)` si `B.FEC_ATE` es una columna fecha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás convirtiendo una fecha a un formato que depende de la configuración de idioma y fecha de tu conexión. Y no sería un problema mayor, pero empieza a generar errores cuando lo quieres comparar con un campo de tipo datetime (o cualquier tipo de fecha/hora). Lo mejor es mantenernos con puros tipos temporales.

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.PTA, B.ORD, A.NOM,A.DIR,A.INS, C.DES,B.PED, A.FCG,B.FEC_ATE,A.FNA, A.HCL,D.OBS, SUM (F.GTS) "UB"
FROM dbo.CLIPAC A
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIORD B ON  A.ORI=B.OPA 
AND A.PAC = B.PAC 
INNER JOIN dbo.CLINST C ON A.INS = C.INS
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIHCL D ON A.HCL = D.HCL
INNER JOIN dbo.CLIIOR E ON B.PTA = E.PTA AND B.PAC=E.ORD
INNER JOIN dbo.CLINOM F ON E.PFA= F.COD
WHERE A.OBS LIKE 'DOM%'  
AND A.NOM NOT LIKE '%ANULADA' 
AND F.CLA = 'NT'  
AND B.FEC_ATE BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE(),MONTH(GETDATE(), 16)
                  AND EOMONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY B.PTA, B.ORD, A.NOM,A.DIR,A.INS, C.DES,B.PED, A.FCG,B.FEC_ATE,A.FNA, A.HCL,D.OBS
ORDER BY 9,1,2
```